# Yahoo Pipes and YQL: Can I strip HTML tags from my items?

Tags: xpath, yahoo-pipes, yql

Given [this pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=788ae518ac2922267a74a17a86ba94f0), I'm trying to strip all HTML tags from -div class="post-text"- and return plain text.

In other words, for [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215548/whats-the-hardest-or-most-misunderstood-aspect-of-linq), the first item should return:

> "Background: Over the next month, I'll
>   be giving three talks...
>   {...}
>   complex generic signatures (e.g. Enumerable.Join)"

Can anyone assist?

At face value, it would be convenient to get the HTML-less text content in the YQL select clause, but I'd settle for a subsequent Regex module if that is the only way.

Comment: Apparently, yql can get the innerText of an element (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661256/663996#663996)... but I couldn't get it to work with a div. :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the formatted view of YQL as result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588736/how-to-get-the-formatted-view-of-yql-as-result)