# How to get the formatted view of YQL as result?

Tags: pipe, concatenation, yql

YQL gives out result only in tree view. Is there any way to get the result in Formatted view??

Comment: What 'format' would you like the view to be?

Comment: i'd like to view in HTML format...

Well, i could use yahoo pipes fetch module to get pages in HTML but that fetch module can fetch pages of less than 200k. But the YQL can fetch pages more than 200K. Therefore, i want to use YQL, but i need the fetched page in HTML format

Answer (score 2):

Use an XSLT stylesheet to create a formatted view. Here is an example for an RSS feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="XML" encoding="utf-8"
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
doctype-system=http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match='//channel'>
<page>
<content>
<module>
<header layout="simple">
<layout-items>
<block class="title">YDN Widget</block>
</layout-items>
</header>
</module>
<xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
</content>
</page>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
<placard layout="card" class="link">
<layout-items>
<image resource="ybang"/>
<block class="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></block>
<block class="description"><xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/></block>
<block class="subtext"><xsl:value-of select="category"/></block>
</layout-items>
<load resource="{link}" event="activate"/>
</placard>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Referenced using the following YQL syntax:

```
select * from xslt where url="//foo.rss" and stylesheet="//bar.xsl"
```