# Regexp to simplify Yahoo Answers Feed Title

Tags: regex, yahoo-api

I am trying to parse the yahoo answers feed - http://answers.yahoo.com/rss/allq
The issue is that the titles have

[ Category ] : Open Question :

in every title that I do not want... I want to write a regexp to remove this...

anything that we can make to remove all the letters in the starting [ and the first : should do it.

there is a space after the `:` also, we need to remove that too.

Thanks for this in advance, I will also try to find a solution myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Yahoo's [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) service to parse this feed (or other web pages)?

- [Querying html using Yahoo YQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661256/querying-html-using-yahoo-yql)
- [Yahoo! Query Language](http://css.dzone.com/articles/yahoo-query-language)
- [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

They already have sample queries for you to get at Yahoo Answers data:

- **answers.getbycategory:**
  http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20answers.getbycategory%20where%20category_id%3D2115500137%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22
- **answers.getbyuser:**
  http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20answers.getbyuser%20where%20user_id%3D%22YbaMGtHFaa%22
- **answers.getquestion:**
  http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20answers.getquestion%20where%20question_id%3D%2220090526102023AAkRbch%22
- **answers.search:**
  http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20answers.search%20where%20query%3D%22cars%22%20and%20category_id%3D2115500137%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22

*(Just an FYI in case you weren't aware of this convenient service.  I use it instead of screen scraping with RegEx's.)*

Comment: Great. Thanks a ton! Both answers are superb!

Answer (score 1):

the following regex should do the job:

```
^\[.*?:
```

Usage sample in c#:

```
string resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^\[.*?: ", "");
```

What it does is start with an `[` bracket and take any characters until it matches a `:` and take the follwing space.

Hope this helps,
Tom.

Thanks @ [cmptrgeekken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33212/cmptrgeekken) for pointing the non greedy thing out!

Comment: Might want to make that `.*?` so it's a non-greedy match. Otherwise, if the title itself has a colon in it, this regex would remove everything up to the second colon